# Can one specify a file content-type to download using Wget?

Tags: linux, web-crawler, wget

I want to use wget to download files linked from the main page of a website, but I only want to download text/html files.  Is it possible to limit wget to text/html files based on the mime content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think they have implemented this yet. As it is still on there bug list.

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=21148

You might have to do everything by file extension

Answer (score 1):

Wget2 has this feature.

```
--filter-mime-type    Specify a list of mime types to be saved or ignored`

### `--filter-mime-type=list`

Specify a comma-separated list of MIME types that will be downloaded.  Elements of list may contain wildcards.
If a MIME type starts with the character '!' it won't be downloaded, this is useful when trying to download
something with exceptions. For example, download everything except images:

  wget2 -r https://<site>/<document> --filter-mime-type=*,\!image/*

It is also useful to download files that are compatible with an application of your system. For instance,
download every file that is compatible with LibreOffice Writer from a website using the recursive mode:

  wget2 -r https://<site>/<document> --filter-mime-type=$(sed -r '/^MimeType=/!d;s/^MimeType=//;s/;/,/g' /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-writer.desktop)
```

Wget2 has not been released as of today, but will be soon. Debian unstable already has an alpha version shipped.

Look at https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget2 for more info. You can post questions/comments directly to bug-wget@gnu.org.

Answer (score -1):

Add the header to the options

```
wget --header 'Content-type: text/html'
```